# Is there any way to comment this with shortcuts?

Tags: eclipse

If i want to implement following comment in shorts-cut, what should i do ?

I found shift+alt+j only comment before method body, i just want to comment in method.

thanks in advance

```
    /**
     ** @modify  by grandstream   
     ** @oginal functions    将原先的代码注释 在这部分
     ** @desc 说明修改的原因   
     ** start modify
    */

xxxxxxxxxx   新的代码
xxxxxxxxx


    /**
** end modify
    */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a template (Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Templates). Insert your comments there, you can use ${line_selection} as a placeholder for the lines that are selected when you use the template.

Such templates are then "Surround with"-Templates, the shortcut for a list of them ist Shift + Alt + Z. So select your code xxxxx, press the Shift + Alt + Z and select your new template to insert the comments.